# ensure の最中に例外が発生すると何がおきますか？

Tags: ruby

ensure は、対応する `begin ~ end` のブロックを抜ける際に、たとえ例外が発生していたとしても、必ずその句の内容を実行させるようにするための記法です。

ふと、例外でブロックを抜ける際に実行される ensure の最中に、例外が発生してしまった場合に、何が起こるのか気になりました。

#### 質問

- 例外発生時の ensure 句実行中の最中に、また別の例外がそこで発生した場合、 ruby はどのような挙動を示しますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ensure に限らず、 ruby において例外発生中に別の例外を raise した場合、その新しい例外に対して古い例外を cause に設定した状態で、新しい方の例外が送出されます。

具体例として:

```
def raise_ex
  raise 'foo'
rescue
  raise 'bar'
ensure
  raise 'piyo'
end

begin
  raise_ex
rescue StandardError => ex
  p ex
  p ex.cause
  p ex.cause.cause
  p ex.cause.cause.cause
end

### 出力
# #<RuntimeError: piyo>
# #<RuntimeError: bar>
# #<RuntimeError: foo>
# nil
```

#### 環境

- 2.5.1